# Android OnItemTouchListener for gallery widget?

Tags: android, gallery, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I'm using the gallery widget to show some image in my application. I see some method how `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)` that allow me to manage the click evenet on single item of my gallery with the variable position. Now i would like to do the same but with the touch event. But i don't find any `onItemTouchListener` or something like this.

Comment: First of all, why do you want to do the same thing using touch event, if you've already done it using onItemClick? Is there something special you want to achieve?

Comment: With onItemClick i show the image to all screen, while with on touch event i want to manage this event to delete the image on swipe up.

Comment: Edit your question and put some source code. I might be able to help you.

Comment: My question is if there is the same thing about onItemClick but with the touch event. To respond you don't need some code. You have only to  to told me if there is a method or not. Anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: Implementing and overriding onTouch is not the same as it is with onItemClick. onTouchEvent has only a MotionEvent argument from where you can retrieve a few data like, the touchedX and touchedY values. Please see [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) for further information.